# nodejs: How to nicely import constants?

Tags: node.js, import, enums, constants

I have one file with constant definitions (common.js):

```
var Errors = Object.freeze({
    SUCCESS: {code: 0, message: 'Success'},
    NOT_ENOUGH_ARGUMENTS: {code: 1, message: 'Not enough arguments provided'},
    NOT_ALLOWED_ARGUMENT: {code: 2, message: 'Argument value is not allowed'}
});

module.exports = Errors;
```

And another file that uses this one (profile.js):

```
var Errors = require('../../common');

module.exports.profileCreate = function (req, res) {
    var name = req.query.name;
    var email = req.query.email;

    if (!name || !email) {
        res
            .status(403)
            .json({error: Errors.NOT_ENOUGH_ARGUMENTS});
        return;
    }

    // ...
}
```

It looks to me that `module.exports` in first file and `var Errors=require()` in second one are having excessive syntax. Moreover I don't know what to do if I'd like to make some more enum constants instead of single `Errors` object.

What I have to do in order to use my enum object in other files of the project? Should I write down a bunch of exports for every enum object in the future, like:

```
module.exports.Errors = Object.freeze({ ... });
module.exports.Result = Object.freeze({ ... });
// ...etc
```

Comment: Why not create an error handler, like a separate module for your custom errors. As for `enums` you only need to create exports if its being used by other modules.

Comment: I have a modular architecture, so one error handler for all API errors will lead to complexity and overengineering. I suppose that my current solution with some simple universal constants is much cleaner than having spaghetti error handling methods in separate module.